Show that is a relation is acyclic and antisymmetric, then it is complete and transitive.
Consider a set $X$ and a relation $R \subset X \times X$. I read that there's set-theoretic result that if a relation is acyclic and antisymmetric, then it can be extended to a preference relation. (For reference, a preference relation $\succeq_X$ is a binary relation on $X \times X$ that is complete and transitive.)
I don't have a proof. I rather have a counterexample. Take $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and suppose $R$ is such that $$\forall \ x,y \in X \backslash \{4\} : x R y \iff x \geq y.$$
$R$ is acyclic and antisymmetric but is it complete?
I understand that the element $4$ is not related with any other element. But if we define $R$ in a way that it is defined over the entire cartesian space $X \times X$, then completeness is trivial, isn't it? And once completeness holds, transitivity does as well: for $x \neq y \neq z$, $(x R y) \land (y R z) \implies (x R z)$ since otherwise, acyclicity would not hold.

What is your definition of complete relation?

"I read that there's set-theoretic result..." Where did you read this? Always cite your sources, please!

How do you define acyclicity?

You are missing the "extended to"-part. A relation $R\subseteq X\times X$ extends the relation $R'\subseteq X\times X$ if $R'\subseteq R$.
Without further restriction, every relation on a set $X$ can be extended to a preference relation on $X$, namely the trivial relation $X\times X$.
You are likely referring to the nontrivial result (a version of the Szpilrajn extension theorem) that an anti-symmetric and acyclic relation $R$ can be extended to a preference relation $P$ with the property that whenever $x R y$ holds but not $y R x$, then $xP y$ holds but not $yP x$ (strict preferences are preserved). This is trivially the case in your example because the case $xRy$ but not $yRx$ never occurs.

Thank you for the answer. Moreover, what a pleasant surprise Prof. Greinecker: I picked this up while learning economics (I missed the precise details) and if I had posted this on Econ SE, you probably would have been the one to answer this there as well.

Glad to be of help. And "Michael" suffices; I might be a dog on the internet.
